# How to prevent VSC from adding "require"?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

While editing some JS files, VSC systematically adds "`require()`" calls, which I have to remove as quickly

How to prevent VSC from adding theses lines with "`require`"?

Thanks
Didier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `jsconfig.json` file inside your project and set `"javascript.suggest.autoImports"` to `false` as [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports) to disable auto-import IntelliSense in your code-base.

You can alternatively disable it globally by going to VSC settings (`Ctrl + ,`), search for "javascript auto import" and disable there.